# Copying 2D Array into 3D w/ one less row n times

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2D array, and I need to make it into a 3D array - with the next layer starting with the second row of the first layer.

This is my best attempt to visually show what I want to do, with four 'layers':

```
# original array
dat = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 9]
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 9],
                [2, 2, 2, 2, 9],
                [3, 3, 3, 3, 9],
                [4, 4, 4, 4, 9],
                [5, 5, 5, 5, 9],
                [6, 6, 6, 6, 9],
                [7, 7, 7, 7, 9],
                [8, 8, 8, 8, 9]], np.int32
              )

#dat.shape
#(8, 5)

layers = 4

# new 3d array

# first 'layer'
[0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 9],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 9],
[3, 3, 3, 3, 9],
[4, 4, 4, 4, 9],
[5, 5, 5, 5, 9]

# second 'layer'
[1, 1, 1, 1, 9],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 9],
[3, 3, 3, 3, 9],
[4, 4, 4, 4, 9],
[5, 5, 5, 5, 9],
[6, 6, 6, 6, 9]

# third 'layer'
[2, 2, 2, 2, 9],
[3, 3, 3, 3, 9],
[4, 4, 4, 4, 9],
[5, 5, 5, 5, 9],
[6, 6, 6, 6, 9],
[7, 7, 7, 7, 9]

# fourth 'layer'
[3, 3, 3, 3, 9],
[4, 4, 4, 4, 9],
[5, 5, 5, 5, 9],
[6, 6, 6, 6, 9],
[7, 7, 7, 7, 9],
[8, 8, 8, 8, 9]

# new shape: (rows, layers, columns)
#dat.shape
#(6, 4, 5)
```

I realize my visual representation of the layers might not be the way I say it is at the end, but that is the shape that I'm trying to get it in.

Solutions that I've tried include a variation of `np.repeat(dat[:, :, np.newaxis], steps, axis=2)` but for some reason I struggle once it's more than two dimensions.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1:** Here's one approach using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
layers = 4
L = dat.shape[0]-layers+1
out = dat[np.arange(L) + np.arange(layers)[:,None]]
```

If you actually need a `(6,4,5)` shaped array, we would need slight modification :

```
out = dat[np.arange(L)[:,None] + np.arange(layers)]
```

**Approach #2:** Here's another with [`NumPy strides`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) -

```
strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
m,n = dat.strides
N = dat.shape[1]
out = strided(dat, shape = (layers,L,N), strides= (m,N*n,n))
```

For `(6,4,5)` shaped output array,

```
out = strided(dat, shape = (L,layers,N), strides= (N*n,m,n))
```

Note that this second method would create a view into input array `dat` and is very efficient to be created. If you need a copy instead, append `.copy()` at the end : `out.copy()`.

Sample output for `(6,4,5)` output -

```
In [267]: out[:,0,:]
Out[267]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 9],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 9],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 9],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 9],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 9]])

In [268]: out[:,1,:]
Out[268]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 9],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 9],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 9],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 9],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 9],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 9]])

In [269]: out[:,2,:]
Out[269]: 
array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 9],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 9],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 9],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 9],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 9],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 9]])

In [270]: out[:,3,:]
Out[270]: 
array([[3, 3, 3, 3, 9],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 9],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 9],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 9],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 9],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: Ah thank you! That's very close but I need the shape to be `(6, 4, 5)` (I realize my visual representation wasn't the best / accurate)

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you so much! I've been trying to do this for hours now haha I'm mostly a pandas guy and I'm realizing I really need some help on numpy!

Comment: @Zach Sorry yeah, these broadcasting/multi-dim indexing and strides aren't the easiest of stuffs, but are very helpful once you get to use it.

Comment: Ya for sure! Out of curiosity, do either of these perform better than the other on large datasets (+1-5 million records)?

Comment: @Zach Go with the strides one.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again!